# How to prevent the popup of keyboard for editText while activity is loaded

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a survey activity which consists of option types as radio button, checkbox, textbox. I am using EditText to get user's response for text box. I am inflating the EditText dynamically from recycler view adapter.
But whenever this activity is called, keyboard also pops up with the cursor in the EditText box. But I only want the keyboard to open only when the user touches on the EditText. I have tried few possible methods, but didn't work and need your assistance. Thanks in advance!!

```
fun showTextBox(answerLL : LinearLayout, currentItem : QuestionList, position: Int, draftOptions : MutableList<Draft>) {
    answerLL.removeAllViews()
    var optMaster : OptionMaster
    answerLL.setPadding(0, 0, 55, 0)
    val et = EditText(mActivity)
    et.setMinLines(1);
    et.setMaxLines(10);
    et.setCursorVisible(true);
    et.requestFocusFromTouch();
 //   et.requestFocus()
    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
    val lp = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    et.setLayoutParams(lp);
    et.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    et.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    et.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
    et.setPaddingRelative(15, 7, 7, 7);
    et.setPadding(15, 7, 7, 7);
    et.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    et.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                textListener.textValueEntered(currentItem.questionMaster.qmID, s.toString())

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    })
    for(draft in draftOptions){
        if (draft.quesId == currentItem.questionMaster.qmID){
            et.setText(draft.optValue)
        }
    }
    answerLL.addView(et)
    }
```

Comment: Make the first (vertically first) TextBox or any other non-EditText `focusable`. Your edit text is probably the first focusable element in the layout and thats why the keyboard opens. Or... dig deeper and figure out why it's opening.

Comment: But by default, the first focusable element takes focus, and if it ends up being an EditText, the keyboard will show up. The easy solution is to make something else above it (or before it) focusable as well. The harder solution is to differentiate whether the keyboard should be opened and when that is, and closing the keyboard programatically until it should be opened. Or change the edit text's focusability until it should be ready to accept input (e.g. when the activity has finished loading)

Comment: @vishnu jm when you are adding edit text you have set the focus of edit text to false , only in this way you can achieve what you need, ```et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
et.setFocusable(false);```

Answer (score 0):

check your `windowSoftInputMode`attribute in manifest file, activity tag